# Seeing all records in lookup dialog

Tags: lookup

Could we make the standard lookup dialog more usable. When new users enter the org and try to create a record with a lookup field in it- since they are not aware of the existing parent record names it ends up being difficult to select a parent record. Is there any way or hack to bring in all the parent records, at least some, so that user can choose easily. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really doubt this is possible with standard layouts having look-ups dialog. According to [SFDC Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_lookupdialog.htm&language=en)

> When you perform a blank lookup, a list of all recently used records
> displays. Search results vary for some object types:
>
> - For standard lookups of products and queues, the dialog shows an    alphabetical listing of the first 50 records.
> - For standard lookups of campaigns, the dialog shows the first 100 active campaigns.
> - For the    asset standard lookup on a case, the dialog shows all the assets tied    to the contact on the case, if any.
> - For standard or enhanced lookups    of users, the dialog shows a list of recently accessed user records    from across your
>   organization.
>
> Custom objects are listed in descending order by the date when you most recently accessed them.
> It can be achieved by custom VF page and lookup.

Comment: Thanks manjit. Could you think of any hack by which we can make the new user see the recent records in the lookup dialog. Like he has accesed them before?